# Spring Cloud Data Flow Grafana Prometheus not showing stream data

Tags: spring-cloud, grafana, prometheus, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I launch Spring cloud data flow with docker-compose base on this website.

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/

I created 3 apps, Source, Processor & Sink.

I ran

```
export STREAM_APPS_URI=https://dataflow.spring.io/Einstein-BUILD-SNAPSHOT-stream-applications-kafka-maven
```

When I run `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml -f ./docker-compose-prometheus.yml` up, all my containers start up as specified in the docker-compose.yml and docker-compose-prometheus.yml.

I proceed to register the 3 applications and then create a stream with them.I then run it.

[image]

**Question 1:**
The status of the stream is always "Deploying". Shouldn't it be Deployed?

**Question 2:**

When I click on the "Grafana" icon, it launches the Grafana page but there is no data on it. Why is it so? I am using kafka as my messaging middleware as shown below.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[image]

This is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.dso.info.io</groupId>
    <artifactId>usage-detail-sender-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>usage-detail-sender-kafka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <prometheus-rsocket-spring.version>0.8.0</prometheus-rsocket-spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- prometheus-rsocket monitoring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus-rsocket-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus-rsocket-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What do you see when you go to your applications' `/metrics` page? (Or whatever endpoint they are configured to export Prometheus metrics to.) If the relevant stream metrics are there (you can check what those metrics are by clicking *Edit* on one of the Grafana panels and looking at the query), then the problem is on the Prometheus/Grafana end of things. If the metrics are not there (or the `/metrics` page is missing altogether) then it's on the application end.

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am getting same problem

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue adding some dependencies and some entries on properties.

pom.xml:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.metrics.export.prometheus.rsocket.enabled=true
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.metrics.export.prometheus.rsocket.host=prometheus-rsocket-proxy
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.metrics.export.prometheus.rsocket.port=7001
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.endpoint.health.show-components=always
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```